# Problemas para configurar o MySQL no Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

A aplicação MySQL Installer está falhando na parte de configuração, exatamente no momento em que cria o serviço, alguém sabe a razão deste problema? Obs: estou conectado com um usuário local e administrador.

O resultado do log é:

> Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]
>   Attempting to grant Network Service require filesystem permissions.
>   This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.
>   This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.
>   Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service [if necessary]

Comment: está executando o instalador como administrador ? (mesmo o usuário sendo administrador)

Comment: Sim, eu executo a aplicação como administrador

Answer (score 0):

Isso pode te ajudar:

Instala o Mysql -installer-web-community-5.6.23.0.msi

seleciona  com MySQL servers 5.6.22 - X64 e MySQL Connectors -> Connector ODBC/5.3.4 - 64

Executa -(ready to configure) -> Next

Config type: Development machine, tudo padrao (TCP/IP, Port: 3306, Open firewall)

Digita no MySQL Root Password

MySQL user Accounts -> Add user (username, password, OK) -> Next

Configure MySQL Server as a Windows Service (MARCADO)

Windows Service Name: MySQL56 (default)

inicia o Mysql Server junto do windows

Execute o serviço como.. Standard System Account (MARCADO)

Next -> Execute, devera aparecer a caixa de dialogo que deve estar emcoberta pelas outras janelas "Configuration of MySQL Server is taking longer than expected..., aqui clicka OK.